# How to handle "flood wait" errors when using telethon.sync?

Tags: telethon

**Looks like sync version of the client doesn't throw any errors?
What is the right way to handle errors when working with telethon.sync?**

the code below results in client going to "sleep", but no errors are cought.

I tried to do the same with explicit exception for `FloodWaitError`, it doesn't solve the issue.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_logging(level=logging.INFO)

tg = TelegramClient(
    'anon',
    api_id=config.API_ID,
    api_hash=config.API_HASH,
)

with tg as client:
    try:
        result = client(GetFullChannelRequest(-1001100118939))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        break;
        # print('Flood wait for ', e.seconds)
        # time.sleep(e.seconds)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`telethon.sync` doesn't change the behavior of exceptions. However, `FloodWaitError` is not a `ValueError`, so your `except` won't catch it. The following will work:

```
from telethon import errors

try:
    ...
except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
    print('Flood wait for ', e.seconds)
```

Note that the library automatically sleeps if the flood error is less than a minute by default, in which case it will wait and not raise for convenience.

Comment: i follw this config . the below running result but no user was added

Flood wait for  633
Adding 2001418425
Flood wait for  633
Adding 2040411495
Flood wait for  633
Adding 2143377980
Flood wait for  633
Adding 1571223042
Flood wait for  633
Adding 1651307838
Flood wait for  633
Adding 1651318275
Flood wait for  633
Adding 2127877100
Flood wait for  633
Adding 425408304
Flood wait for  633
Adding 550893208
Flood wait for  633
Adding 688524596
Flood wait for  633